# Unable to compile SignalR from GitHub

Tags: c#, signalr

I just downloaded [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) from [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), because I would like to use the [WinRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) client sample, but I'm not able to compile the source because the katana directory is empty.
How can I fix this and compile the project?

Comment: Without including more information, I doubt anyone can help you here. What version did you clone and what is the exact error message the compiler gives?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version in zip from gitub.
In the repository I find the empty katana directory, but when i open the solution with Visual Studio, I see that some projects are missing

Answer (score 0):

Read the readme, it describes how to build SignalR. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR#building-the-source

Also, there's no WinRT sample in our source...